# C++ Design: single function performing multiple tasks vs multiple functions performing single task

Tags: c++, methods

While designing a C++ class, suppose I have following two options:

Option 1: One method with a long argument list and the method performs multiple tasks.
Option 2: Separate method for each task (each method would have smaller argument lists).

Clearly, in general, option 2 is preferable as it produces cleaner code. However, if these methods were for the sole purpose of being "helpers" to some other method then in case of option 2 I would have to incur the overhead of multiple function calls whereas option 1 would have only one function call.

Would the supposed performance gain (due to fewer function calls) justify choosing option 1 in such (extreme) a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would the supposed performance gain (due to fewer function calls) justify choosing option 1 in such (extreme) a case?

IMO, the performance gain here is negligible enough to not sacrifice maintainability of code, particularly in enterprise applications, where functions with large argument lists and lots of lines of code are difficult to modify/debug. Such functions must be broken down into multiple smaller functions where each one performs a well-defined step that is part of a larger task.

Comment: The only time that expanded functions (That is to say less function calls) would be beneficial is in the case of an embedded system where the over-head might not be there.

Comment: @M4rc, thanks for the response. I was wondering if there aren't any compiler switches to truly "inline" functions declared so, for optimizing the compiled code for embedded systems!

Comment: That immediately come to mind I'd imagine not, though disabling optimizations should in theory leave the executable as close to how you type it as possible, leaving you with more control. But as with anything else, it's *just* a suggestion. I'm fairly certain embedded C/C++ compilers include different sort of optimizations for such situations, though.

Comment: @M4rc, got it. My strong inclination towards maintainability comes from currently working on a legacy system where it is being so difficult to reverse-engineer the functional aspects from this kind of code and wanted to share the experience of a potential developer down the lane sometime who would look at the code. Thanks for your suggestion, btw.

Comment: Lol no need to defend yourself my friend, especially since IMO you're completely right. The thing I love about programming is, there's more then one way to get to home base.

Answer (score 0):

Your job is to write good, clean and working code. It's the compiler's job to make it efficient. And apparently, it does it alot better then you can ever do.

So yea, always go with option number two. If you want efficiency, write clean and let the compiler do it's work. (Btw you can compile with -O3 flag to increase the optimizations even further)

Answer (score 0):

**Give one entity one cohesive responsibility**
is a title of article 5 in C++ Coding Standards by Alexandrescu.

In my opinion, you will lose clarity, increase maintenance cost, and have a greater chance to introduce bugs in a "do it all" scenario.

It might be wise to measure the performance of separate function calls vs a function that has to perform code path logic internally on each call.